# SoundCloud getCommentsFromTrack

Tags: android, soundcloud

I am using the SDK from: https://github.com/voidplus/soundcloud-java-library
The only issue I have is getting comments of specific track using getCommentsFromTrack.

```
ArrayList<Comment> mTrackComments;
mTrackComments = mSoundCloud.getCommentsFromTrack(Integer.parseInt(mSongsList.get(0).get(AppConstants.KEY_ID)));
```

I did the login, get the track list, keep the track id in a list with: `track.getId()` , but it seems the method getCommentsFromTrack is always returning null

Could someone help me in getting comments for specific track in SoundCloud?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed the bug and updated the dependencies: https://github.com/voidplus/soundcloud-java-library/commit/a6e818033b06879af9bb463116eb4130b8285526

Update the jar file and try the following code:

```
ArrayList<Track> tracks = soundcloud.findTrack("Chromatics");
for(Track track:tracks){
    System.out.println(track.getId()+" "+track.getCommentCount());
    if(track.getCommentCount()>0){
        ArrayList<Comment> comments = soundcloud.getCommentsFromTrack(track.getId());
        System.out.println(comments.get(0).getBody());
        break;
    }
}
```

Regards,
Darius